# What happened to all of these questions?

Tags: discussion

So during the definition phase of Lifehacks.SE there was a place where people posted example questions: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409?phase=definition

Are these going to be asked sometime? I know many aren't, and I was wondering if it was okay to ask some of these questions myself. I feel they should be transferred in some sort of way, if possible.

Comment: I asked [my highest score proposed question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks/76752#76752) on [the main site](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/261/137).

Answer (score 6):

One thing to keep in mind is that although these questions were asked in the definition stage, the site is still being defined. Some issues were found when we went into beta, and we have created a [new scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/the-scope-of-lifehacks) to clear these up. You should read through it if you haven't already, and make sure the questions you ask fit in the scope.

As for the moral part, yes, it's fine to ask questions from the proposal in beta, even if they were originally posted by another user. There is no need to add credits to the original poster; that clutters the post and is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

They're not asked automatically, because they're really just question titles.

No one owns them, so ask away! ( *but check first if they've already been asked, because some have already* )

Also, as always, make sure you keep the rules of asking questions here, notably showing effort in asking questions, and including a previously tried (and failed) solution with your question*. ;-)

---

**That may not be policy **yet**, but it's being worked on as we speak.*